# Files inside of External storage won’t show in nextcloud (Snap Package)

Tags: permissions, files, snap, nextcloud

The following two are snapshots of my file explorer:

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the attached images files within my hard drive aren't showing in nextcloud but do show in other places. It is added through the administration using these settings:

> Imgur: The magic of the Internet

When I try and write to the drive it says

> unable to create file from template:
> Imgur: The magic of the Internet

This is what happens when I rescan my files:

[image]

It seems to be a permission issue, one problem is that I don't know how to fix this.
Hope you can help me fixing this.